# 20' run of romex unsupported through confined-space basement finished ceiling?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, confined-space

I've 2-runs of 12/2 w/G romex supported to studs from breaker box up to where it needs to run unsupported 20' through and alongside (parallel) floor joists of finished floor/basement ceiling for 20' to a junction box at other end where again it'll be firmly supported to studs. My QUESTION is it OK to have it laying unsupported on the sheetrock ceiling while only being fastened to studs on both ends. Basement ceiling is finished I prefer not chopping into it??

Answer (score 3):

### This is fine

What you are describing falls under NEC 334.30(B) point 1:

> **(B) Unsupported Cables.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be
> permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>
> (1) Is fished between access points through concealed spaces
> in finished buildings or structures and supporting is
> impracticable.

So, go ahead and fish the cable through the ceiling as you plan to do.

Comment: Once again, I learn something here almost every day.   Thanks 3ph +